# Json field dependency for unit conversion

Tags: json, dependencies, jsonschema, unit-conversion

I have this json schema defined :

```
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "kg": {
              "type": "number",
              "multipleOf": 0.01,
            },
            "lbs": {
              "type": "number",
              "multipleOf": 0.01,
            }
          }
```

I want a dependency between Kg and Lbs, so that when a user enters weight for kg,
the weight for lbs should get auto populated with value in kg * 2.20462262 and vice-versa for kg,
with weight equals to lbs * 0.45359237.

For eg if user enter 5 for field kg, the lbs field should reflect 11.02 as value, and when user enters 5 for field lbs, the kg field should reflect 2.26 as value.

I know about json dependency, but not how to access it's value if the referred value is not of type enum.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use JSON Schema to express constraints between two different data values. Your application will need to do that.

I would suggest making *either* `kg` or `lbs` (note the inconsistency in pluralization there?) a required property, and then your application will convert into the preferred units based on that:

```
{ 
  type: object,
  anyOf: [
    { required: [ kg ] },
    { required: [ lbs ] }
  ],
  properties:
    ...
}
```